# magento set base image if i have path to image

Tags: magento-1.8, image

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'FN244403');
$product1ID = $product1->getId();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "Select * from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE `entity_id` = '$product1ID' 

LIMIT 1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
echo $path = $rows[0]['value'];
```

So, how i can now set Base, Small image, etc?
I am try do it, but this not help

```
try {
    $product1->setSmallImage($path)
        ->setThumbnail($path)
        ->setImage($path)
        ->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $path is an absolute, filesystem URL, then you can run the following:

```
$product1->addImageToMediaGallery($path, array( 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail' ), false, false);
```

The array seen here sets the image to be the main image, small image and thumbnail.  Just ommit those you don't need.

Function reference here: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#addImageToMediaGallery describes that the function takes the following parameters:

```
void addImageToMediaGallery (string $file, [string|array $mediaAttribute = null], [boolean $move = false], [boolean $exclude = true]) 

string $file: file path of image in file system 
string|array $mediaAttribute: code of attribute with type 'media_image', leave blank if image should be only in gallery 
boolean $move: if true, it will move source file    
boolean $exclude: mark image as disabled in product page view
```